# How to join two pandas DataFrame when the join condition column has different name

Tags: pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames

1.

```
a   b   join
1   2   'a'
3   1   'b'
```

2.

```
c    d  Join
2    3  'a'
4    2  'b'
```

want to join on (join, Join), which represent the same thing with slightly different tokens

how to solve this join cleanly ?

This is a toy example, real data can be larger

Comment: have a look at [`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging), there are two keyword arguments named `left_on` and `right_on`.

Comment: Just to elaborate on Cel's comment try `df_left.merge(df_right, left_on='join', right_on='Join', how='outer')` see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the columns to the same name - i.e. the second dataframe to 'Join' to 'join'.

df2.columns = ['c', 'd','join']

You can then perform your join on 'join'.